# Resume training for stable baseline model PPO

Tags: reinforcement-learning, snapshot, stable-baselines

I wonder if I can resume training from checkpoints after saving logs in stable baseline as from what I understood from the documentation that CheckpointCallback can work as snapshots (yet not sure about this)

This code creates logs but I am not sure if I can use them to resume training and if this even possible using this method

```
controller = PPO('MlpPolicy', environment, verbose=0, clip_range=0.15, device='auto', learning_rate=0.00001, )
    checkpoint_callback = CheckpointCallback(save_freq=1000, save_path= output_dir +'./logs/', name_prefix='rl_model')
    controller.learn(total_timesteps=int(timesteps), callback=checkpoint_callback)
```

I tried using tensorboard_log as it is what I found clear explanations about how to do this (save model and resume training) but I get the error zsh: illegal hardware instruction, and I never got output from it or link to where I can monitor my model, I couldn't find much solutions for this either

I hope that someone can help, and if what I am doing is wrong then can you please let me know the best way to do this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every callback, which overrides `on_step` method (such as `CheckPointCallback`), returns a boolean value that tells your `train` and consequently `learn` calls whether they should further proceed. Training resumes automatically. Sometimes you may wish to break your training instead, then you can write a callback, whose `on_step` will return `false` by certain conditions, e.g., when the number of episodes exceeds a threshold.

As for tensorboard log: it is about saving your training metrics, not a model.